# ASP.NET Core Identity - Force user to configure 2FA

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core Identity, and I need a way to "force" certain users to configure 2FA. In other words, once a user logs in with their email and password, they should be sent to the 'configure 2FA' screen without allowing them to perform other actions until they have successfully configured 2FA.

I can't find any documentation related to this functionality or any method that could tell me if 2FA is enabled for that user but not configured yet.

Is there any functionality available in ASP.NET Identity Core to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Identity gives you the ability to check if 2FA is enabled. From this data you can perform a check within your login method to fail authentication if this is not enabled on the account.
Example:

```
if(!ApplicationUser.TwoFactorEnabeld) {
    //Fail the login or stop some action.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question maybe was not clear enough, but if I do as you suggest, the user wouldn't be able to configure 2FA, as far as I understood. My objective is for the user to log in and if 2FA is enabled (but not configured), send them directly to the Configure 2FA screen.
I'm working on a solution. If I manage to come up with something useful, I'll post my answer here too.

Comment: Yeah, Im assuming you already have the ability to setup 2FA within your application? If so then you can use the check shown in the example above to redirect them upon login. It may also be useful to override the `Authorize` attribute and do this check there thus any page that requires a user session will also require the user to have 2FA setup. Also within the attribute you can redirect them when they try and access any authorized page, to your 2FA setup page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd460317(v=vs.100)